# Automatically set parent reference on child items

Tags: c#

I have a class that contains an `IList<T>` property called `Children`. Each child should reference its parent. My solution has been to set the `ChildClass.Parent` property in the `ParentClass.Children` getter. Is there a better way, or is this the best solution?

```
class ParentClass
{
    private IList<ChildClass> _children;

    public virtual IList<ChildClass> Children
    {
        get
        {
            // make sure each child refers to its parent (this)
            foreach (ChildClass c in _children)
            {
                c.Parent = c.Parent ?? this;
            }
            return _children;
        }
        set
        {
            _children = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It could just be me...but this looks like a bad design.

If it's a true Parent -> Child relationship, you shouldn't allow anybody to create an Orphan Child. Therefore, the Parent should be set on the Child at the time of creation.

I would probably do something like:

```
class ChildClass
{
    private ParentClass _parent;

    public ChildClass(ParentClass parent)
    {
        _parent = parent;
    }
}
```

And then:

```
class ParentClass
{
    private List<ChildClass> _children;

    public virtual ReadOnlyCollection<ChildClass> Children
    {
        get
        {
            return _children.AsReadOnly();
        }
    }

    public virtual ChildClass CreateChild()
    {
        // Set parent in child class constructor
        ChildClass newChild = new ChildClass(this);

        _children.Add(newChild);

        return newChild;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless you've got other people consuming your API.
The kind of mentality that's happy to make extreme generalizations such as "a child object should never be able to exist without having a parent object" and enforce that on other programmers is what can cause some dev with a real world edge case scenario hours of pain and frustration.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your solution is that if all the children and parents are correctly linked, your code will re-link them each time the internal child collection is retrieved.  Also, it seems that this problem exists because you are returning a reference to a private collection, after which you lose control of the elements it contains.

I suggest the following:

Provide `Add(ChildCLass)` and `Remove(ChildClass)` methods on `ParentClass`, and enforce the parent-child constraint there.  This allows children to be created anywhere, and be linked correctly when belonging to the hierarchy.  When the are removed from the hierarchy, the are no longer linked.

Do not return a reference to your internal `ChildClass` collection unless the collection is immutable.  Returning a `ReadOnlyCollection` or `IEnumerable` is preferable.

Examples:

```
class ChildClass
{
    // Prevent unauthorized clients from overriding the Parent reference.
    public ParentClass Parent { get; internal set; }

    // ... other methods and properties ...
}

class ParentClass
{
    private IList<ChildClass> _children;

    public void AddChild(ChildClass child)
    {
        _children.Add(child);
        child.Parent = this;
    }

    public RemoveChild(ChildClass child)
    {
        _children.Remove(child);
        child.Parent = null;
    }

    public IList<ChildClass> Children
    {
        get { return _children.AsReadOnly(); }
    }
}
```